# variable substitution (what do you call/name this method)?

Tags: bash, variables

Say in bash I have:

```
c=3

b3=4
```

instead of:

```
echo $b3
```

what kinda of command to have output of "4" ?
I tried below but couldn't.

1. `echo $b($(c))`
2. `echo $b{!c}`
3. `echo $b${c}`
4. `echo ${d[$c]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an indirect reference for that:

```
$ c=3
$ b3=4
$ d=b$c
$ echo "${!d}"
4
```

Although usually instead of indirect references, arrays should be used when possible.

Comment: documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion